# What does ".best_estimator_" return? Why do 'best_estimator_[0]', 'best_estimator_[1]' show different random_state?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I'm trying to get the 'best_estimator_' from 'RandomizedSearchCV' (ultimately I'm trying to plot the SHAP graph from it). Why is it returning something that could be accessed through index? I understand that it's returning the "Estimator that was chosen by the search, i.e. estimator which gave highest score on the left out data".
Shouldn't it only return a single estimator, instead of a few elements that could be accessed by indexes?
What are these different regressors returned here? Which one should I take?

---

These are different results based on code

```
model_RandomizedSearchCV = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=rf,param_distributions = random_grid, n_iter = 10, cv = 3, verbose=2, random_state=1, n_jobs = -1)

# Fit the model with Randomized Search CV to select best hyperparameters
model_RandomizedSearchCV.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

```
model_RandomizedSearchCV.best_estimator_
```

returns:
RandomForestRegressor(max_depth=70, max_features='sqrt', min_samples_leaf=2,
n_estimators=600)

```
model_RandomizedSearchCV.best_estimator_[0]
```

returns:
DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=70, max_features='sqrt', min_samples_leaf=2,
random_state=180493417)

```
model_RandomizedSearchCV.best_estimator_[1]
```

returns:
DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=70, max_features='sqrt', min_samples_leaf=2,
random_state=1819987716)

---

I used model_RandomizedSearchCV.best_estimator_[0] since only 'random_state' looks different in these examples.

Answer (score 1):

A [`RandomForestClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier) is a collection of [`DecisionTreeClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier). The number of trees in the forest can be set with `n_estimators`.

```py
In [1]: from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
   ...: from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
   ...: X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=10, n_classes=2,
   ...:                            random_state=0)
   ...: forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=200, random_state=0)
   ...: forest.fit(X, y)
   ...: 
   ...: forest
Out[1]: RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=200, random_state=0)

In [2]: forest[0]
Out[2]: DecisionTreeClassifier(max_features='sqrt', random_state=209652396)

In [3]: forest[1]
Out[3]: DecisionTreeClassifier(max_features='sqrt', random_state=398764591)
```

From the [scikit-learn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#forest):

> The `sklearn.ensemble` module includes two averaging algorithms based on randomized decision trees: the RandomForest algorithm and the Extra-Trees method. Both algorithms are perturb-and-combine techniques [B1998] specifically designed for trees. This means a diverse set of classifiers is created by introducing randomness in the classifier construction. The prediction of the ensemble is given as the averaged prediction of the individual classifiers.